# WordPress p2p custom query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a MySQL table and need to get the `p2p_to` column value by querying `p2p_from` (53,126).

What query would work?

```
ID  p2p_from   p2p_to

0   53         215 
1   129        12
2   124        9 
3   18         215 
4   15         5 
5   126        215
```

```
AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->p2p.p2p_to 
AND $wpdb->p2p.p2p_from = '53'
AND $wpdb->p2p.p2p_from = '126'
```

---

full query which is being run. but results are weird

```
SELECT     SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.,
           wp_p2p.
FROM       wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_p2p
WHERE      1=1
AND        wp_posts.post_type = 'news-articles'
AND        ((
                                 wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
AND        (
                      wp_p2p.p2p_type = 'practice_areas_to_news_articles'
           OR         wp_p2p.p2p_type = 'attorneys_to_news_articles')
AND        wp_p2p.p2p_from IN
           (
                     SELECT    t1.p2p_to
                     FROM      wp_p2p t1
                     LEFT JOIN wp_p2p t2
                     ON        t2.p2p_to = t1.p2p_to
                     AND       t2.p2p_from = '53'
                     WHERE     t1.p2p_from = '126')
AND        wp_posts.id = wp_p2p.p2p_to
ORDER BY   wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT      0, 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the query. 

plugin url : https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
wp_posts.*, t1.*, 
t1.p2p_to AS t1_p2p_to, 
t2.p2p_to AS t2_p2p_to, 
t1.p2p_from AS t1_p2p_from, 
t2.p2p_from AS t2_p2p_from
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_p2p t1 ON wp_posts.ID = t1.p2p_to
INNER JOIN wp_p2p t2 ON t2.p2p_to = t1.p2p_to
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'news-articles' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
AND (
t1.p2p_type = 'practice_areas_to_news_articles' 
OR t1.p2p_type = 'attorneys_to_news_articles'
) 
AND (t2.p2p_from = '53' AND t1.p2p_from = '126' )
```